# Ruby: scan binary IO for regex

Tags: regex, ruby, binary

I'm looking for an elegant way to scan a ruby [`File`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html) containing binary data for a regular expression.

To be clear, my hangup is not confusion about applying regexes to binary. It's just that because the file is binary, I'd like to avoid `gets` and `readline`. And I'd like to avoid reading the entire file at once.

Is there a function in the ruby core that will do this? Or do I need to build and manage my own buffer?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't really care if strings are UTF-8, Latin-1, or binary. They're just strings. Regular expressions work just fine. The `encoding` property should be set accordingly, obviously, and the file opened in the correct mode, but other than that, not a big deal.

When working with binary files, lines are irrelevant, so use tools like [`IO#read`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/IO.html#method-i-read) to pull in arbitrary chunks.

If the file isn't especially large, read in the whole file at once and work with it that way.